# Get forecast from previous month for each month in matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-bi-report-server

The table contains actual sales and forecast sales for each month.

```
ProjectKey | Sales | ForDate | Snapshot | Scenario  
10         |20     |122018   | 092018   | 3  
10         |22     |122018   | 102018   | 3  
10         |21     |122018   | 112018   | 3  
10         |23     |122018   | 122018   | 1
```

There is a corresponding forecast for each month.

- Scenario 1 = actual value
- Scenario 3 = forecast.
- ForDate = which month was the forecast done for
- Snapshop = date when the forecast was done.

In this case, Dec 2018 contains 3 forecasts.

I need a matrix showing each month's actual sales, forecast from only last month. So if month is Nov, forecast from Oct, If month is Dec, Forecast from Nov and so on.

Note: There are many projects, ForDate for each month. Both ForDate and Snapshot related to DimDate Key (role playing).

Desired output:
Below is matrix for expanded years. I want to get only Nov Forecast for December, Dec Forecast for January and so on.
[image]

Comment: can you please show an example of your desired output?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg - added desired result